# Compile and execute java via bash shell

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, jar

I'm trying to write a shell code that will execute my Java program. I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
COMPILECMD="javac server.jar"
RUNCMD="java -jar server.jar 12777"

$COMPILECMD
$RUNCMD
```

But I got this error:

> error: Class names, 'server.jar', are only accepted if annotation
>   processing is explicitly requested 1 error Failed to load Main-Class
>   manifest attribute from server.jar

In the command line I don't use the jar file, I just compile and then execute:

```
javac server.java 
java server 12777
```

Comment: `javac` compiles Java source files into class files - it doesn't create a Jar.  To do that, you need to use the `jar` command as well (and configure what the main-class is so it can create the appropriate manifest).  However, you might like to consider using `ant` or `maven` to perform the compilation and jarring up of the class files.

Comment: Since you know what works from the command line, why are you doing something different in the shell script? As Greg said, if you want to build a jarfile you can do that, but you need to use the right sequence of commands to do so, and if you want `server` to be the default `main()` class of the jar you need to also create a manifest file saying so.

Comment: offtopic comment, but ["shell code"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) has a different meaning. :-) What you're writing here is usually called "shell script" or "shell program", though the terms are not that distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The *typical* way to build a Java program into a JAR file from the shell is to use the `ant` utility.

Its home (and documentation) is here: http://ant.apache.org/

Essentially, you'd write (or use a tool to write) a `build.xml` in your project folder, and then run `ant` to compile, bundle, et al.

(Disclaimer: I'm not a *fan* of Ant, but it *is*, I believe, the most common/popular tool in the Java universe for this task.)

---

You *can* also use traditional Unix Makefiles, if you're familiar with them. Some rules like:

```
     CLASSES= Server.class Supporting.class

     %.class:   %.java
           javac $<

     %.jar:  $(CLASSES) Manifest.mf
           jar cfm $@ Manifest.mf $(CLASSES)
```

---

You *could* also use a straight-ahead shell script:

```
      javac Server.java
      javac Supporting.java
      jar cfm Server.jar Manifest.mf Server.class Supporting.class
```

However, maintaining this is liable to be a nightmare if your project grows beyond a few files.

---

There are other tools available, as well, but these are the most typical ones I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get wrong understanding.
jar is created by jar command not by javac command.

jar command create a jar file (zip file containing all the class inside)
javac command just compile and transform .java to .class only

Example compile-command:

```
javac server.java; jar cvf server.jar server.class
```

You may find the following link helping.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html